# nhibernate dialect error : seems to be a bug

Tags: nhibernate

I am using an oracle database, so defined dialect as Oracle9Dialect.
But it throws error :

"Could not load type NHibernate.Dialect.
Oracle9Dialect. Possible
cause: no assembly name specified."

I just change the dialect as MsSql2000Dialect without changing
driver_class, it works. But, in this case i cannot use oracle spesific
features..

any suggestions?

```
<hibernate-configuration  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
               <session-factory name="NHibernate.Test">
                       <property  name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver</ property>
                       <property name="connection.connection_string">
                               User ID=hr;Password=hr;Data Source=192.168.189.4/orcl
                       </property>
                       <property name="adonet.batch_size">10</property>
                       <property name="show_sql">false</property>
                       <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2000Dialect</property>
                       <property name="use_outer_join">true</property>
                       <property name="command_timeout">60</property>
                       <property name="query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'</property>
                       <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu</property>
                       <mapping assembly="CoreHR"  />
               </session-factory>
       </hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no longer a class called `NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle9Dialect` in NHibernate 2.1. The class is now called `NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle9iDialect`.